# I'm doing a get request with fetch in a django app, it works in development but not in production and cannot get the problem

Tags: django, heroku, fetch, jsonresponse

The application is deployed on heroku. When I run the program on my machine it works fine, but in production I get different errors. In Google Chrome in the console I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at
> position 0

In Firefox the error in the console is as follows

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at
> line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I received the following report from Sentry:

> Exception gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed   File
> "urllib3\connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
> conn = connection.create_connection(   File "urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
> for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):   File "socket.py", line 953, in getaddrinfo
> for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
>
> NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x00000177DC7693A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
> 11001] getaddrinfo failed   File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line
> 699, in urlopen
> httplib_response = self._make_request(   File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
> self._validate_conn(conn)   File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1010, in _validate_conn
> conn.connect()   File "urllib3\connection.py", line 353, in connect
> conn = self._new_conn()   File "urllib3\connection.py", line 181, in _new_conn
> raise NewConnectionError(
>
> MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.wordreference.com',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x00000177DC7693A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
> 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))   File "requests\adapters.py", line 439,
> in send
> resp = conn.urlopen(   File "urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
> retries = retries.increment(   File "urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
> raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
>
> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.wordreference.com',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x00000177DC7693A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
> 11001] getaddrinfo failed')) (5 additional frame(s) were not
> displayed) ...   File "requests\api.py", line 75, in get
> return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)   File "requests\api.py", line 61, in request
> return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)   File "requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
> resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)   File "requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
> r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "requests\adapters.py", line 516, in send
> raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)

The most relevant code is below. I don't have much experience and I don't know how to identify the problem, I would be very grateful for any help I can get.

**views.py**

```
def translate_word(request, word):
    wr = WordReference('es', 'en')
    wr_obj = wr.translate(word)
    entries = wr_obj['translations'][0]['entries']
    twlist = []
    for entry in entries:
        for dict in entry['to_word']:
            if dict['meaning'] not in twlist:
                twlist.append(dict['meaning'])

    return JsonResponse({"twlist": twlist}, safe=False)
```

**demo.js**

```
translate: (word) => {
  fetch(`/translate/${word}`, {
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', //Necessary to work with request.is_ajax()
  },
  })
  .then(response => {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(data => {
    // code to display the data on the html, the error occurs in the previous .then
  })
},
```

Comment: Looks like connection to `www.wordreference.com` is timed out, check if it is accessible from production machine

Comment: Thank you very much @Adithya, this is correct, I run the command wr = WordReference('es', 'en') and I don't get response, I get the following error
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn  conn = connection.create_connection( File  "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection   raise err  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable